\marginnote: strange behavior with image and text
\marginnote of LaTeX does not accept both image and text in the two options left [] and right {} margins in the same command. I had to put image and text only in the right option {} only.
Why this behavior? Can it be corrected?
I would put image and text in the two margins at the same time

you can use \includegraphics anywhere that you can typeset text. If you have an error most likely there is an error in your input but you have shown neither your input nor an error message so it is hard to help.

If I had to guess, I would guess you are using \includegraphics with an optional argument inside another optional argument. For all such commands using standard argument handling, you need { } to hide the inner [] so \foo[{...\something[...]{..}}] not  \foo[...\something[...]{..}]

Please help us help you and add a minimal working example (MWE) (or maybe in your case not working, but complete example) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with \documentclass{...} and ending with \end{document}.

BTW: I often see code using package marginnote and command \marginnote when \marginpar would be at least as good or maybe even better. Without seeing any code, it would of course be highly speculative to assume such a thing here as well.

% marginnote does not like this and does not show all in the margin
\marginnote[\includegraphics… +  text]{\includegraphics…  +  text}
% I have to put all in the right side only and this is ok
\marginnote{\includegraphics…  +  text}

You incomplete (abstracted) code in your comment is not suitable to reproduce the issue. Please read the page linked in my first comment.

Note also: Using the optional and the mandatory argument does not mean that something is placed in the left and the right margin. Instead the optional argument is used iff it is printed in the left margin and the mandatory argument is used iff it is printed in the right margin. This is analogous to \marginpar. To print something in the other margin you need to use \reversemarginpar. See a LaTeX introduction/tutorial for more information about \marginpar, \reversemarginpar, \normalmarginpar.

"marginnote does not like this" computer programs do not like or dislike anything. If you have a syntax error in your input you will get an error message, but you have not shown any input and not shown any error message so you make it very hard to help, but I guess my guess above is correct and you are missing a {..} group.

Thank to David I solved the problem writing all left and all right contents between new curly brackets: \marginnote[{ left content}]{{ right content}}

I’m voting to close this question because the problem was solved by comments, and the OP could even post an answer.

Thanks to David:  I solved the problem writing each left and right contents between others curly brackets. The code portion below shows the content correctly in the margin:
 \marginnote[{left content: image + text}]{{right content: image + text}} 

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
